# How to break up an implication into two subgoals in Coq?

Tags: coq, coq-tactic, implication

Say I have the following:

```
Lemma my_lemma :
  forall a b c,
    a -> (b -> c) -> d.
Proof.
intros.
```

Then, above the line, I get:

```
X : a
X0 : b -> c
```

Let's say that in my proof, I know I'm going to need `c` somewhere. And I know how to prove `b` from `a`, but it's not very easy. One possibility is:

```
assert b.
+ (* proof of b here *)
+ (* proof using c here *)
```

In this simple case, that's quite painless. However, I want to achieve the same effect without specifying `b`, because I often have hypotheses with more complicated premises that I don't want to type out explicitly in `assert`.

`pose` doesn't do what I want because it requires me to prove `a` first, so automation tactics don't work as well because they don't know that I'm trying to prove `a`. `apply` doesn't do what I want either because it requires me to turn my goal into the same form as the implication first, which also doesn't play nice with automation tactics.

In summary, I want to be able to take a hypothesis `H` that's an implication, and get two subgoals:

- One to prove the premise of `H`.
- One to prove the same goal I already had, given the conclusion of `H` as a new hypothesis.
  And I want to do this without explicitly typing out the premise of `H`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [`lapply`](https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/tactics.html#coq:tacv.lapply) gets closest to the desired behaviour:

> Variant `lapply <term>`
>
> This tactic applies to any goal, say `G`. The argument term has to be well-formed in the current context, its type being reducible to a non-dependent product `A -> B` with `B` possibly containing products. Then it generates two subgoals `B->G` and `A`. Applying `lapply H` (where `H` has type `A->B` and `B` does not start with a product) does the same as giving the sequence `cut B. 2:apply H.` where `cut` is described below.

In your example, we get:

```
Lemma my_lemma :
  forall a b c d,
    a -> (b -> c) -> d.
Proof.
  intros.
  lapply X0.
  + intro.
    (* prove d using c *)
    admit.
  + (* prove b *)
    admit.
Admitted.
```